# How to increase the awx cli result limit of 25

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm working with the awx cli (19.1.0) and awx (13.0.0) in an environment with over 100 servers

When (e.g.) querying failed or changed results with:

`awx --conf.host https://my.awx --conf.username myuser --conf.password mypass -k -f human --filter 'event_display,event_data,host_name,play,task,stdout' job_events list --job 1234 --event runner_on_ok --changed true > /tmp/tmp`

I only get exactly 25 results.
(This fits to the pagination of the awx api?!)
Is there an option to get every result of an awx run?
([ARA](http://ara.recordsansible.org/) would be great alternative to the cli, but it's not applicable for my environment/task)

---

**Update/Hint**
I wasnt aware that one seem to only get the correct command-line help (`--help`) if successfully authenticated (see [my comment to the answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1063803/how-to-increase-the-awx-cli-result-limit-of-25/1063908#comment1385958_1063908))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch all results, add the flag --all to the query.

```
usage: awx job_events list [-h] [--all] [-f {json,yaml,jq,human}]
                       [--filter TEXT] [--conf.color BOOLEAN] [-v]
                       [--type {job_event}] [--created CREATED]
                       [--modified MODIFIED] [--job ID]
                       [--event {runner_on_failed,runner_on_start,runner_on_ok,runner_on_error,runner_on_skipped,runner_on_unreachable,runner_on_no_hosts,runner_on_async_poll,runner_on_async_ok,runner_on_async_failed,runner_item_on_ok,runner_item_on_failed,runner_item_on_skipped,runner_retry,runner_on_file_diff,playbook_on_start,playbook_on_notify,playbook_on_include,playbook_on_no_hosts_matched,playbook_on_no_hosts_remaining,playbook_on_task_start,playbook_on_vars_prompt,playbook_on_setup,playbook_on_import_for_host,playbook_on_not_import_for_host,playbook_on_play_start,playbook_on_stats,debug,verbose,deprecated,warning,system_warning,error}]
                       [--counter INTEGER] [--event_data JSON/YAML]
                       [--failed BOOLEAN] [--changed BOOLEAN]
                       [--uuid TEXT] [--parent_uuid TEXT] [--host ID]
                       [--host_name TEXT] [--playbook TEXT] [--play TEXT]
                       [--task TEXT] [--role TEXT] [--stdout TEXT]
                       [--start_line INTEGER] [--end_line INTEGER]
                       [--verbosity INTEGER]

--all

    fetch all pages of content from the API when returning results (instead of just the first page)
```

Reference: [Ansible Tower/AWX CLI v3.8.3 User Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/reference.html#cmdoption-awx-job_events-list-all)

Comment: wow, at first I was embarrassed of not seeing this, BUT if (on manjaro) I call `awx job_events list --help` these parameters are not listed! Only when I execute an authenticated command like `awx --conf.host https://real.existing.host --conf.username real.existinguser --conf.password myCorrectPassword job_events list --help` I get the full help with all parameters like you have printed... thats very odd

Comment: No big deal. I miss a ton of stuff in documentation all of the time. Tends to happen when you have 50 tabs open in firefox. lol Glad to have helped.